# Find and replace not working - dataframe spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:

`df.show`

```
+----------+-----+
| createdon|count|
+----------+-----+
|2017-06-28|    1|
|2017-06-17|    2|
|2017-05-20|    1|
|2017-06-23|    2|
|2017-06-16|    3|
|2017-06-30|    1|
```

I want to replace the count values by 0, where it is greater than 1, i.e., the resultant dataframe should be:

```
+----------+-----+
| createdon|count|
+----------+-----+
|2017-06-28|    1|
|2017-06-17|    0|
|2017-05-20|    1|
|2017-06-23|    0|
|2017-06-16|    0|
|2017-06-30|    1|
```

I tried the following expression:

`df.withColumn("count", when(($"count" > 1), 0)).show`

but the output was

```
+----------+--------+
| createdon|   count|
+----------+--------+
|2017-06-28|    null|
|2017-06-17|       0|
|2017-05-20|    null|
|2017-06-23|       0|
|2017-06-16|       0|
|2017-06-30|    null|
```

I am not able to understand, why for the value `1`, `null` is getting displayed and how to overcome that. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to chain `otherwise` after `when` to specify the values where the conditions don't hold; In your case, it would be `count` column itself:

```
df.withColumn("count", when(($"count" > 1), 0).otherwise($"count"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `udf` function too

```
def replaceWithZero = udf((col: Int) => if(col > 1) 0 else col) //udf function

df.withColumn("count", replaceWithZero($"count")).show(false) //calling udf function
```

**Note :** `udf` functions should always be the choice only when there is no inbuilt functions as it requires serialization and deserialization of column data.